# Amazon Sage Maker: How to authenticate AWS SageMaker End-Point Request

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sagemaker

I have an aws sagemaker end-point which need to be called from .Net core client, I have used the AWS SDK that deals with SageMaker and provided the required credentials however, always it keeps saying :

The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.

var requestBody = "{'url':'"+"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/05/28/22/11/message-in-a-bottle-3437294_960_720.jpg" + "'}";

```
        var request = new Amazon.SageMakerRuntime.Model.InvokeEndpointRequest()
        {
            EndpointName = "CG-model-v1-endpoint",
            ContentType = "application/json;utf-8",
            Body = new MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestBody)))

        };


        var awsClient = new AmazonSageMakerRuntimeClient(awsAccessKeyId: "XXXX", awsSecretAccessKey: "XXX", region: RegionEndpoint.EUCentral1);

        try
        {
            var resposnse = await awsClient.InvokeEndpointAsync(request);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return ApiResponse<bool>.Create(false);
        }
```

Comment: Things to check: 1) check with the AWS CLI that the credentials actually work , e.g. 'aws sagemaker list-endpoints' 2) Try invoking the same API in your app 3) Make sure you haven't swapped the actual values in your API call (it happens to me all the time!). On a more general note, I would not recommend storing credentials in code, you'll end up pushing them to Github :) You should use an application config instead, or Secrets Manager.

Comment: @JulienSimon when I tried the "aws sagemaker list-endpoints" from CLI , it seems that the credentials are working since I get a response.

Comment: I found the error , it was simply because of the request content-type,it had to be application/json instead of application/json;utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the error , it was simply because of the request content-type,it had to be application/json instead of application/json;utf-8